# Water around shed/ house

Tags: water, waterproofing, water-damage, flooding, french-drain

How do I remove all this water from around my shed garage? It’s an up hill to the street. There is no slope for a french drain. Water goes around on both sides.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The only thing I'd consider would be landscaping., e.g., adding soil, and possibly raisng shed.

Comment: There's that "rain garden" concept, but it looks like you would need quite the reservoir. Displaced soil could raise the grade elsewhere, where you can rent a sod machine, roll the grass up, dump soil, and and roll the grass back on top. A French drain with a pump integrated somewhere is an option. A plant like annual ryegrass can increase infiltration. Or you can get a little pump and use a garden hose to pump it into the storm water system.